# Update an object in a List using Riverpod NotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm using a Riverpod NotifierProvider with a List of data objects as the data source.

```
class FooData {
  final int data1;
  final String data2;
  final String data3;

  FooData({this.data1 = 0, this.data2 = "", this.data3 = "",});

  FooData copyWith({int? data1, String? data2, String? data3,}) {
    return FooData(data1: data1 ?? this.data1, data2: data2 ?? this.data2, data3: data3 ??    this.data3); 
  }

final foodataListProvider = NotifierProvider<FooDataListNotifier, List<FooData>>(FooDataListNotifier.new);

class FooDataListNotifier extends Notifier<List<FooData>> {
  void addFooData(FooData input) {
    state = [...state, input];
  }

  void updateFooAt(int index, {int? data1, String? data2, String? data3}) {
    //This is where I'm not sure what exactly what I need to do to update the state
    //while maintaining the immutability for the list.
    state[index].copyWith(
      data1: data1 ?? state[index].data1,
      data2: data2 ?? state[index].data2, 
      data3: data3 ?? state[index].data3,);
    state = [...state];
  }

}
```

The addFooData method works as expected but I am unable to update the items in the list with the provider.

In my ConsumerWidget I am accessing it by using `final provider = ref.watch(foodataListProvider);`
for the provider and `final notifier = ref.watch(foodataListProvider.notifier);` for the notifier.
Then in an onPressed in a ElevatedButton I access it like this `notifier.updateFooAt(index, data1: "New Data");`

I have tried different updateFooAt implementations like

```
FooData data = state[index]; 
data.copyWith(data1: data1); 
state = [...state, data];
```

and

```
List<FooData> dataList = state; 
dataList[index].copyWith(data1: data1); 
state = [...dataList];
```

I've also accessed it in the onPressed using `ref.read(foodataListProvider.notifier).updateFooAt(index, data1: "New Data");`

When I debug I see that there are new FooData's added to the list but when I try to update them they keep the data from addFooData, they don't update.

I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75582420/update-value-of-variable-inside-list-inside-data-class-using-riverpod-and-copywi) but it uses a list inside the data object. Not that I'm opposed to that but I'd like to figure out how to do it with my setup. A few other questions have given me ideas but not solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Notifier<List<SomeType>> is troublesome`. All updates must be accompanied by a call to `ref.notifyListeners()`. That will solve your immediate problem, but consider using an `IList` (fast immutable collections) or a custom list-holder class instead to make it immutable.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ConsumerStatefulWidget` instead of `ConsumerWidget`